# Error When trying to install a package using dpkg

Tags: debian, software-installation, dpkg, oracle-database

I am trying to install `Oracle SQL Developer` onto a Debian Linux server.

I started off by downloading a package from the Oracle website;

> sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm

I then called the following command to make this into a `.deb` package.

```
alien sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm
```

This command ran successfully and created the new file:

> sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84-2_all.deb

To install this package I then called the following:

```
dpkg -i sqldeveloper_4.0.0.12.27-2_all.deb
```

Which outputted the following:

```
dpkg: warning: downgrading sqldeveloper from 4.0.3.16.84+0.2.3-1 to 4.0.3.16.84-2.
(Reading database ... 33017 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace sqldeveloper 4.0.3.16.84+0.2.3-1 (using sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84-2_all.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement sqldeveloper ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): short read on buffer copy for failed to write to pipe in copy
dpkg-deb: subprocess paste returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84-2_all.deb (--install):
 short read on buffer copy for backend dpkg-deb during `./opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/extensions/oracle.datamodeler/lib/pdfbox-app-1.8.0.jar'
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sqldeveloper_4.0.3.16.84-2_all.deb
```

I have looked through Google to try and find solutions to this problem and have come across similar issues for errors with `--configure` and --uninstall`but nothing for`--install`.

Comment: Quick "is it plugged in check": confirm via `df` that you're not out of disk space and via `df -i` that you're not out of inodes.

Comment: @derobert That's fine. Still over 4GB space free.

Comment: `dpkg: warning: downgrading sqldeveloper from 4.0.3.16.84+0.2.3-1 to 4.0.3.16.84-2.` tells me you already had SQL Developer installed, using a package created with [sqldeveloper-package](https://packages.debian.org/sqldeveloper-package); what was wrong with that version?

Comment: @StephenKitt I've ran in to a few problems with the other package when setting it up, for example, the version I currently have isn't compatible with certain elements of Java I have installed.

Comment: Unfortunately I have never seen Oracle successfully running on Debian. In a previous role it rapidly got to the stage where it became easier simply to install CentOS (or RHEL in our case) and move on with a mixed Debian and CentOS environment.

Comment: @roaima Fair enough, I have taken a  look through Google before and it appears the majority of people are having some sort of issue setting up different Oracle products. I think I will have to try, as you said, just installing anoter OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used **alien** to transform the package format from `.rpm` to `.deb`.

In the most cases that tool works flawless. But rarely it fails building an installable package. Especially if there are some install or config-scripts included in the .rpm package (which are like the pre and post install/remove scripts in a .deb package).

You didn't tell, whether there were some errors or warnings outputted when running **alien**.

It can “run successfully” and produce an empty or broken package nevertheless…

If there were some errors or warnings, have a closer look at them. The messages will likely point in the right direction. But for the following I assume there were no errors outputted by **alien**.

A first check to look for what went wrong would be to extract both package format versions and compare the contents.

First make two temp dirs

```
mkdir /tmp/sqldeveloper.deb /tmp/sqldeveloper.rpm
```

Then extract the `.deb` package

```
dpkg-deb -X sqldeveloper_4.0.0.12.27-2_all.deb /tmp/sqldeveloper.deb
```

And the rpm package

```
cd /tmp/sqldeveloper.rpm
rpm2cpio sqldeveloper-4.0.3.16.84-1.noarch.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

You can then compare the directories with **diff**

```
diff . /tmp/sqldeveloper.deb
```

If there are files missing in the .deb directory, the package was broken by **alien**. Maybe ask the developers of that tool for help then.

But how I read the messages outputted by `dpkg -i` you posted, there is some issue with the packaging by itself, and the file

> ./opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/extensions/oracle.datamodeler/lib/pdfbox-app-1.8.0.jar

couldn't be extracted. Maybe the parent directory is missing or there is some wired access rights problem.

I think that problems will show up when you try to extract the `.deb` archive by hand like shown above.

---

By the way: it's a java software, and the “Other Platforms” versions which is available for download is a zip archive. It will presumably run without installation when extracted in your home directory.